# How do I tune and test the performance of jboss 4.2.2GA connection pool?

Tags: java, performance, jboss, connection-pooling

I know how to use `dbcp`, `c3p0` and `jboss connection pool` basically.

But I've been guided to use `jboss connection pool` first for stability and performance. I also know there are a lot of configuration options for `jboss connection pool`. But I do not exactly know how to tune and test the configuration.  I use `MySql` and `Oracle`.

How do I tune and test the performance of jboss `4.2.2GA` connection pool?